# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'usertype' in 'field list''

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I tried to implement the following code onto my website, but this error appeared:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'usertype' in 'field list'' in /home/multive2/public_html/superdonate/ajax/login.php:63 Stack trace: #0 /home/multive2/public_html/superdonate/ajax/login.php(63): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/multive2/public_html/superdonate/ajax/login.php on line 63"

Why this is happening? *Sorry about my English/ code.*

```
        if(curl_errno($curl)){
            array_push($pageError, getLangString("process-request-error"));
            array_push($pageError, curl_errno($curl));
        } else {
            $returnedDecoded = json_decode($returned, true);
            if(isset($returnedDecoded['success'])){
                if($returnedDecoded['success'] === true){
                    $moveOn = true;
                } else {
                    array_push($pageError, getLangString("retry-captcha"));
                }
            } else {
                array_push($pageError, getLangString("process-request-error"));
            }
        }

    } else {
        $moveOn = true;
    }

    if($moveOn === true) {
        if($_POST['login-type'] == "login"){
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $sql = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT password, usertype FROM users WHERE username=:username");
            $value = array(':username' => $username);
            $sql->execute($value);  -----------------------------> Line 63, Error.
            $result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                $count = $count + 1;
            }
            if($count < 1){
                array_push($pageError, getLangString("incorrect-login"));
            } else {
                if(password_verify($password, $result[0][0]) == true){
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    if($result[0][1] === 'admin'){
                        $_SESSION['admin'] = TRUE;
                    }
                } else {
                    array_push($pageError, getLangString("incorrect-login"));
                }
            }
        } elseif ($_POST['login-type'] == "register"){
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $confirmpassword = $_POST['confirm-password'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $uservalid = FALSE;
            $passvalid = FALSE;
            $emailvalid = FALSE;
            $sql = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=:username");
            $value = array(':username' => $username);
            $sql->execute($value);
            $result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                $count = $count + 1;
            }
            if($count > 0){
                array_push($pageError, getLangString("username-taken"));
            } else {
                if($password === $confirmpassword){
                    if(strlen($username) < 6 OR strlen($username) > 32){
                            array_push($pageError, getLangString("username-length-error"));
                    } else {
                            $uservalid = TRUE;
                    }
                    if(strlen($password) < 8){
                        array_push($pageError, getLangString("password-length-error"));
                    } else {
                        $passvalid = TRUE;
                    }

                    $url = $sdonateapiurl;
                    $data = array('action' => 'validateemail', 'apikey' => $sdonateapi, 'email' => $_POST['email']);
                    $options = array(
                        'http' => array(
                            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                            'method'  => 'POST',
                            'content' => http_build_query($data),
                        ),
                    );
                    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
                    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

                    if($result === FALSE){
                        array_push($pageError, getLangString("process-request-error"));
                    } elseif($result === "apiproblem") {
                        array_push($pageError, getLangString("api-key-problem"));
                    } elseif($result === "EMAILINVALID") {
                        array_push($pageError, getLangString("invalid-email-error"));
                    } elseif($result === "EMAILVALID") {
                        $emailvalid = true;
                    }

                    if($uservalid === TRUE AND $passvalid === TRUE AND $emailvalid === true){
                        $hashed = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                        if($hashed === FALSE){
                            array_push($pageError, getLangString("account-registration-error"));
                        } else {
                            $sql = $dbcon->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username, email, password, usertype) VALUES(:username, :email, :password, :usertype)");
                            $values = array(':username' => $username, ':email' => $email, ':password' => $hashed, ':usertype' => 'user');
                            $sql->execute($values);
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    array_push($pageError, getLangString("password-mismatch-error"));
                }
            }
        } elseif($_POST['login-type'] == "resetpassword"){

            $key = $_POST['reset-password-key'];
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];

            $sql = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT * FROM resetpassword WHERE username=:username AND resetkey=:resetkey");
            $values = array(':username' => $username, ':resetkey' => $key);
            $sql->execute($values);
            $results = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $resultscount = $sql->rowCount();

            if($resultscount > 0){
                if(strtotime($results[0]['expires']) > time() - 86400){
                    if($password === $confirmpassword){
                        if(strlen($password) > 7){
                            $hashed = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                            if($hashed === FALSE){
                                array_push($pageError, getLangString("password-change-error"));
                            } else {
                                $sql = $dbcon->prepare("UPDATE users SET password=:password WHERE username=:username");
                                $values = array(':password' => $hashed, ':username' => $username);
                                $sql->execute($values);
                                $sql = $dbcon->prepare("DELETE FROM resetpassword WHERE username=:username AND resetkey=:resetkey");
                                $values = array(':username' => $username, ':resetkey' => $key);
                                $sql->execute($values);
                            }
                        } else {
                            array_push($pageError, getLangString("password-length-error"));
                        }
                    } else {
                        array_push($pageError, getLangString("password-mismatch-error"));
                    }
                } else {
                    array_push($pageError, getLangString("password-link-expired-error"));
                }
            } else {
                array_push($pageError, getLangString("password-link-invalid-error"));
            }
        } else {
            array_push($pageError, getLangString("invalid-request-error"));
        }
    }
} else {
    array_push($pageError, getLangString("retry-captcha"));
}
}

if(count($pageError) > 0){
    foreach ($pageError as $key => $value) {
       print('<span>' . $value . '</span><br>');
    }
}
```

*Sorry about this*

[DESCRIBE users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5RSi.png)

Comment: Without seeing your database schema, it's impossible to know. More than likely, it's because you don't have that column in your `users` table.

Comment: It's you RoboLaserMan! You learned how to copy paste!

Comment: Lol, sorry about before. I didn't know how to ask a question properly. I guess it would be wise of me to include a picture of my 'users' table from my database?

Comment: @AbhayPatani97 yes

Comment: If you have PHPMyAdmin, or command line MySQL just do 
`DESCRIBE users   `  and copy paste the output

Comment: I did 'DESCRIBE users' and an output appeared in phpMyAdmin, how do I copy and paste the tables over? (Sorry as you can tell, I am not very experienced in MySQL...) @DuaneLortie

Comment: A screenshot will suffice

Comment: The `usertype` column does NOT exist. You probably meant to use `username`. If not, then don't include it in the SELECT.

Comment: Screenshot is added above, sorry about not showing the actual image above. Still get used to using 'Stack Overflow'. "user_type column in the field_test table?" @Fred-ii-

Comment: As I suspected, you do **not** have a column in your database called `usertype`. If you need that value, you need to add it. The error message is crystal clear.

Comment: Again: you have no column named `usertype`, there isn't anything else anyone can say here, except to keep repeating ourselves.

Comment: Ohh, I shall try add it right now. I tried to make a 'field_test' table in the database, thinking I needed to add a column called 'usertype' in there. Thanks, I shall try it out... @JeremyHarris

Comment: Sorry about the pointless questions, my mind is a daze. @Fred-ii-

Comment: @AbhayPatani97 I know the feeling, it happens to every one of us, every once in a while ;-) Too much coffee in the morning can also do that *lol*

Comment: @AbhayPatani97 I posted a community wiki answer below which you can mark off as solved to close the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Lol, that's true. Coffee is a killer. Thanks for the help. :D

Comment: @AbhayPatani97 You're welcome.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Cool, I shall mark it off right now. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome (again) ;;-) and welcome to Stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as a community wiki. (no rep should come of this).

The error is clear, the `usertype` column does not exist.

Either you create it, or remove it from the queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write your variable within quote ('$variable') which holds the value usertype.